# Intermediate wireless connection

Tags: wireless-networking, router

Good evening/morning

I have a laptop PC I connect to my home internet through a wireless ADSL router. I bought a desktop PC (and I intend to buy more). I don't want to use a long ethernet cable to connect my desktop PC to the internet. I already have a set of short ethernet cables and I am wondering if there is a device that can connect to the router through wifi and which can then connect to my desktop using the ethernet cable?

Thanks.

PS: Please do not suggest the obvious USB wifi adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a wireless bridge. Several of the home network device vendors sell them. A wireless bridge will connect to the Wi-Fi network, and provide ethernet connections (typically four) for remote devices to connect to the Wi-Fi network through ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any device for this purpose, because this kind of wireless networks work in a short range, so birding the network using WiFi isn't cost-benefit solution.

There is a solution. Use a `Mikrotik Wireless Router` such as `RB951` series. They have a `WiFi` chipset and multiple `Ethernet` interfaces (5 or more). Make a wireless client and bridge it with other interfaces.

Comment: **Make a wireless client and bridge it with other interfaces.**. I do not really understand. Please can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Are you familiar with Mikrotik Router OS?

Comment: Yes I do. But I am not sure I have ever read something about wireless in the OS doc.

Comment: See [here](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Connect_to_an_Available_Wireless_Network). This learns you how to make a WiFi client on Mikrotik Router OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inexpensive gadget known as Wireless Repeater or Range Extender.
See here https://www.google.com/search?q=Wireless+Repeater&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8